# touchesBegan withEvent is not responding in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchesbegan

What I had done in my xib file is that,
Initially I had an uiImageView and over that I had an UIScrollView on which i had put so many other controls.
Earlier I was not having scroll view so my touchesBegan event was working properly but now after putting UIScrollView its not responding.
I am new in iOS so please tell me what to do??
What I want to do is to hide my keyboard which appears for my UITextView, whenever I touch anywhere on screen.
So please help me out...
the code of my touchesBegan method is:

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([self.txtLoginId isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != self.txtLoginId)
{
    [self.txtLoginId resignFirstResponder];
}
if ([self.txtPassword isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != self.txtPassword)
{
    [self.txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
}
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably, your `scrollView` has its property `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`. In this case, the `scrollView` receives the touches, and they will not be forwarded to your method `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.
Simply try to set this property to `NO`. This can be done in storyboard in the view section of the `scrollView`, or programmatically.